# trying to use fetch in componentDidMount shows undefined [react native]

Tags: javascript, react-native, fetch

Here's my componentDidMount:

```
componentDidMount(){
    return fetch(API_URL + "/users?email=test@test.com").then(
      (response) => response.json()
    ).then( (responseJson) => {
      console.log("response is " + responseJson.category)
    }).catch((error) => console.log(error))
}
```

However the console.log that you see there prints:

```
 response is undefined
```

When I acces my API through that exact same URL I get:

```
[{"category":"Donante","_id":"123","address":"street 32","email":"test@test.com", "__v":0}]
```

So why am I unable to get the data in my code?

Comment: your response is an array - containing only one object, at least in this case. So it looks like you want `responseJson[0].category`

Comment: omg so simple, thanks it worked!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're getting an array back as a response, make sure you access an individual element of that array first!

ie, change your console.log to `"response is" + responseJson[0].category`

Answer (score 0):

This might be happening because the promise returned by the `fetch` function, is not fulfilled yet when you're trying to access the response object.

So, you might want to refactor the code with something like the following:

```
componentDidMount(){
  const promise = fetch(API_URL + "/users?email=test@test.com").then(res => res.json());

  Promise.allSettled([promise]).then(([responseJson]) => {
    // you can access your responseJson here
    console.log(`response is ${responseJson.category}`);
  }
}
```

The `Promise.allSettled` function returns a promise, that only resolves until the promises given by param are either fulfilled or rejected. In that way, you're accessing the  You can check for more details [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled).